# Right-clicking on a JFreeChart

Tags: java, jfreechart

It seems to me that the `chartMouseClicked` method gets called only when the user left-clicks on a chart. What's being called when the user right-clicks on a chart and the popup menu is displayed? I want to do something in the background when the user right-clicks before the popup menu is displayed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[`ChartPanel`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html) implements `MouseListener` to display the context menu. To accommodate [disparate platforms](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup), it checks `isPopupTrigger()` in both [`mousePressed()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#line.1845) and [`mouseReleased()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#line.2009). You may need to override both methods.