# how to add Menu support for each series in chartPanel

Tags: jfreechart

I want to add menu support for each series in my StepArea chart in jfreeChart.
Can anybody tell be how we can do this in java?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7758759/right-clicking-on-a-jfreechart ?

Answer (score 1):

Write an [`Action`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for each menu item like they show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11895709/261156), and use the `Action` to make your menu item, like they shown [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html).